# FBRequestConnection does not provide UI while FBDialog Does

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I am using FBRequestConnetion to post[only text] on the wall. But, the problem there is deprecated class in latest FacebookSDK , which is FBDialog.

So, Is there any other UIComponent in latest FacebookSDK, through which I can achieve the FBDialog Behaviour to post on the wall.

Or I have to design my own UI and use FBRequestConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at SDK that was just released + this link for a a native UI built on top of iOS6:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

You can also look at the updated sample HelloFacebookSample that's included in the SDK that shows how you can post a status update for a user.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused about this too. Looking at the *HelloFacebookSample* sample from the SDK, that's what I understand:

- In the previous SDK, we could display a dialog where the user can customise the message, and choose to post or cancel. I think this didn't require any special Facebook permissions.
- Now *iOS6* has a nice native dialog, but the *iOS5* fallback is to post directly using **FBRequestConnection** - which just posts directly without any dialog, and also requires the "publish_action" permission.

I guess I arrived at the same conclusion, if we want a nice dialog on *iOS5*, we have to:

- create the UI ourselves (maybe imitating the IOS6 popup) and ask for the new permission
- or use the deprecated headers in the SDK folder (not sure I'd go there...)